# Application Sandbox Mode

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Good evening!

My trouble is as follows. I've disabled sandbox mode in my app in Facebook dev center. However, nobody, but developers accounts can still use the full functionality of the app. Everyone can get access to newsfeed and contacts list, but only developers have access to inbox mail. 
In the picture bellow you can see the status of my app ( developers mode disabled).
Bundle-ID and all app's information entered correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot from app developer's console]

Comment: Which kind of app is it (mobile, web)? Can you show us some code where you do the Facebook connect?

Comment: Which messaging API are you using? Some of them are only available to developers of the app, regardless of whether the app is in sandbox mode or not, e.g.: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/thread/